# How to get the height of a full html page in Phantomjs (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, viewport

Hi have tried all of these:

```
document.body.scrollHeight
document.body.offsetHeight
document.documentElement.clientHeight
document.documentElement.scrollHeight
document.documentElement.offsetHeight
```

These work in a normal browser but in Phantomjs I get the CMD (command-line window) height.. I want to get the height so that I can crop a screenshot later in the code.. and the height of the page must be as it is being viewed on a normal browser

I'm getting 300 pixels and I want to get the full html page height (that varies dependent on the URL)..

Comment: What are you expecting to get, if there's no actual browser?  Why won't the CMD line window height work simply for testing purposes?  Consider an [edit] to your post to clarify.

Comment: Why wouldn't the height of the CMD window work as a substitute, since Phantom doesn't have an actual physical browser?

Comment: What does CMD height mean? What values do you get and what values do you expect? Please show a complete example script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those values provide the expected values as with other browsers. Full example:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

var url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/';

page.open(url, function(){
    console.log(page.evaluate(function(){
        return JSON.stringify({
            "document.body.scrollHeight": document.body.scrollHeight,
            "document.body.offsetHeight": document.body.offsetHeight,
            "document.documentElement.clientHeight": document.documentElement.clientHeight,
            "document.documentElement.scrollHeight": document.documentElement.scrollHeight
        }, undefined, 4);
    }));
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Output:

```
{
    "document.body.scrollHeight": 8777,
    "document.body.offsetHeight": 8777,
    "document.documentElement.clientHeight": 300,
    "document.documentElement.scrollHeight": 8777
}
```

Reasons why it might not be the case for your:

- The DOM is only accessible through `page.evaluate()`. There exists a `document` object outside of `page.evaluate()`, but it is only a dummy.
- PhantomJS has a default viewport of 400x300 pixels. If the web page is responsive, then it will only use this size.
- Together with the point above, the `<body>` may not be scrollable, but only some child element that has all the (scrollable) content. In which case every value is equal to the viewport height.

Comment: I got nothing in the console log :s

Comment: This script works perfectly for me with PhantomJS 2.0.0 and PhantomJS 1.9.7. Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) and [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) events. Maybe there are errors. If bind is an issue, you need a [shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521).

Comment: It is working now, I was doing something wrong in my initial code, but I will mark your answer as the correct one, thanks ;)